# Load Angular page after DataTable dynamic creation

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I used DataTable dynamiccally

```
'render': function (data, type, full, meta)
{
    return '<td class="inbox-table-icon"><div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-click="togg(' +
    data + ')" ></div></td>'
}
```

In the controller, the function:

```
$rootScope.togg = function (data)
    {console.log("togg");};
```

Function is not called when clicking checkbox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the Html properly binded to the controller. I mean try anything else than this to check if the template is binded to the controller or if angular is working here. you can write `{{1+1}}` in the return template to check if angular is working there it should be 2.

Comment: It's working. the propblem it is only in the properties that rendered by the controller for the data table. Other button in the html call this function and working.(out of the Datatable directive) i think it because the html loaded before the datatable. How can I reload the page , maybe with $compile?